# Is there a way to get customers logged out without calling wp-login.php?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am using woo-commerce. The logout URL is different which includes 'customer-logout'. In reality it again redirects to 'wp-login.php' to make logout process successful.
My question is, when Woo-commerce doesn't call 'wp-login.php' for Logging in, and why does it call for logging out?
I know, this has been asked several times since at-least 5 years, but there is no direct answer.
I am using htaccess password lock for admin area. With this any new/existing customers can register and login without any issues. But, while the customer logs out, since the wp-login.php is called, it asks for htaccess username and password. This implies for all types of users, admins, non-admins too.

Is there a way to Logout Customers without calling wp-login.php?

Edit: I have used logout redirect function too, to redirect customers to custom page after they click on logout. This doesn't work either for me. No matter wp-login.php is called.
PS: Technically, customer logout url is different. It too redirects to wp-login.php

Comment: if your `.htaccess` password lock is correctly set for just the admin area, then it wouldn't be triggered on your `wp-login.php` since this isn't in the `wp-admin` folder. Perhaps it's worth reviewing your .htaccess "password lock".

Comment: Thanks again Paul for reply. This code doesn't work either in my case. If I password lock my wp-admin folder, of course, it asks the ht username and password. By entering that, I am able to access login page.

BUT, if the I directly go my login page, i.e, domain.com/wp-login.php, it doesn't work. I mean, anybody will be able to directly access my login page with password.

Comment: I would assume that your exact problem is not that users can not log out without `wp-login.php` page, but that they are redirected to it after they have been logged out, and what you realy want is for them to be redirected to some other page. If I am correct please edit the question to reflect it.

Comment: Question Edited

Answer (score 0):

I have found a work around for this problem by utilizing Cloudflare Firewall rules. 5 are Free. I used just 2. It works perfectly. Any inputs will be appreciated.
What I did is,

- 1

Blocked direct access to /wp-login.php if it doesn't contain /wp-login.php?action=logout.
So, a customer can easily logout without calling for wp-login.php. No Error.

So now, How do I login?

- 2

Create another rule to allow access to /wp-login.php only if a cookie is found in the browser.
Here, if I want to login, First, I will open my site. Then add a custom predefined cookie. And then access my /wp-login.php. Simple!
That cookie name and value is my key to gain access to login page.